# URL is being changed from webpage but no 301 (redirect) status code. How is this possible and how do I capture the new URL

Tags: python, python-requests, nft

so in the past few days I've been wondering how this works.
Basically Twitter added a new profile feature where you can put /nft at the end of a profile URL and it would show you if that user owns an NFT that is linked with their profile.

Thing is when you put /nft on a user that does not own an NFT (or hasn't linked one with their profile) the URL is changed to the profile page with an /photo at the end of the URL.

How is this possible without a redirection? There is no 301 status_code on the requests made. Also is it possible to fetch this /photo URL using python?

Example:

Profile with linked NFT:
https://twitter.com/STEP1profit/nft

Profile without linked NFT (URL is changed to /photo):
https://twitter.com/theweeknd/nft

Comment: There is no http redirection, url is updated with javascript.

Comment: @Alex is there a way to capture this js url update with python?

Comment: use something to run javascript, like selenium